# Are variables declared side by side in a struct contiguous?

Tags: c++, memory

I know for sure that array elements are stored contiguously, but what if I declared something like this:

```
class A {
    public:
    int a, b, c;
    // or
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

Are the members stored contiguously? I've been thinking if there's a possibility that a variable is stored in between the declaration of `a` and `b` from another process, so that it's not contiguous. But I'm not sure.  Are there any guarantees?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15248697

Comment: Woop okay, i'll mark as duplicate thanks for the links. @n.m. because i tested it and the address is contiguous, so that confuses me a bit i guess.

Comment: There's no possibility of another process "adding" variables to yours.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'll think more about this. Thank you.

Comment: There is a leap of faith between "I have seen it happened once" and "this is guaranteed to happen always no matter what".

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289559/class-layout-in-c-why-are-members-sometimes-ordered

Comment: This question is about contiguity of class instance variables, not initialization order. @closevoters look again.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure there's no semantic difference between `int a, b, c;` and `int a; int b; int c;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` `b` and `c` are guaranteed to be in that order in the struct.

However, in general, there might be structure padding in between any two struct members.  Typically there would be no padding for a struct that only contained `int` members but it would be good practice to not make that assumption.

You could check this at compile-time:

```
static_assert( sizeof(A) == 3 * sizeof(int),  "oops, A had padding" );
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Anyway thank you, i'll then try to avoid using it that way.